# Is there any parameter to set session timeout on jupyterlab?

Tags: jupyter-lab

When I launch Jupyter lab session it is not logging me off .I observed that the inactive session timeout for the web application is not adequate. After testing for about one hour, I concluded that the inactive session timeout was either not configured or longer than 1 hour. I want to set session timeout for this problem, So that session must logoff when user is away for a longer period of time.

1-What is the name of that file?
2-where the file is located?
3-what parameters need to change to resolve (No session timeout).
Kindly provide answer.

[image: Here is a screenshot attached]

Comment: You’ve tagged jupyterhub but only mentioned jupyterlab. Is this a jupyterhub deployment? How is it configured? If not, where/how is your jupyterlab session running?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Thanks for the response, I have edit post and provided screenshot. 
I installed jupyter-lab using pip install jupyterlab.

Comment: it looks like you're running jupyterlab in a local session. why would it log you out? just kill the terminal command which started jupyterlab using `Ctrl+C` if you want to stop the server. But this is not hosted on a different computer - it's like a very fancy python terminal.

Comment: I'm going to drop the jupyterhub tag. [JupyterHub](https://jupyter.org/hub) is a multi-user jupyterlab hosting platform intended to be hosted on a server or cluster. Feel free to add it back in if you really are running jupyterhub - if so, please edit the question to include much more information about your setup and exactly how you configured & deployed jupyterhub so we can help.

Comment: I mean without killing command `Ctrl+c`  it must be log off when a user is away from PC. For the testing purpose I run it in a local session. apart from this we use EKS, LDAP as authenticator

Comment: Please provide more of a description about how you are deploying jupyterhub or jupyterlab. The answer will depend on whether this is a kubernetes cluster deployed with her, a tljh deployment on a Linux server, or a locally hosted jupyterlab session. If it’s the last one, there is no such option.

Answer (score 2):

The file is jupyter_notebook_config in ~/.jupyter/config. You can generate it with 'jupyter notebook --generate_config' per https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/use/config.html#the-python-config-file

The options are listed in https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html

It seems lke MappingKernelManager.cull_idle_timeout and NotebookApp.shutdown_no_activity_timeout would do what you want.

> NotebookApp.shutdown_no_activity_timeout: Int
>
> Default: 0
>
> Shut down the server after N seconds with no kernels or terminals running and no activity. This can be used together with culling idle kernels (MappingKernelManager.cull_idle_timeout) to shutdown the notebook server when it’s not in use. This is not precisely timed: it may shut down up to a minute later. 0 (the default) disables this automatic shutdown.